# MS Powerpoint 2007 L Shape

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint

I am creating a block diagram using the 'L' shape and I want to turn the 'L' 90 degrees and have the text on the top.

I have tried various ways of doing this and I either get the text upside down, back to front or down the side of the 'L'.

How do I get the text to go the right way along the top?

Comment: Adding some examples or helpful screenshots could be helpful, especially with such a 'visual' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, use 3D Text Rotation in format text effects.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?